# Make a div appear between another divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have layout of profile images 4 in row, they are all circle, if I hover on them another div slides right side with aditional information, this info div comes from the center of image circle and is under image, but I want this info div appear on top of other profile images not on its parent div. how is this possible. So you can look at picture: from first picture comes another div which will contain info about user, but I want that div appear over second picture.
here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/geass94/rsw6o1hu/

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="fm-userpreview" id="{user_ID}">
    <div class="img fm-circle" style="background-image: url('{foto}')">
      <img class="invis" src="{foto}">
      <p><a href="">{fullname}[not-fullname]{username}[/not-fullname]</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fm-userfullpreview" id="user-{user_ID}">
  testsdagfasdgdsfghfdshsdfhsdfh
  </div>
</div>

.fm-userpreview
{
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    position: static;
    z-index: -1;
}

.fm-userpreview a
{
    color: #fff;
}

.fm-userpreview p
{
    bottom: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fm-userpreview .fm-circle
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 5px;
}

.fm-userfullpreview
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
}

$('.fm-userpreview').hover(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.fm-userpreview').not($('#'+id)).css('z-index', '-3')
        $('#user-'+id).animate({
            width : 350,
        });
    },function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#user-'+id).animate({
            width : 0,
        });
        $('.fm-userpreview').not($('#'+id)).css('z-index', '-1')
    });
```

[image]

Comment: suggest you create a working demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox so people can play with this and fork modifications

Comment: here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/geass94/rsw6o1hu/
make sure to stretch preview are to fit all 4 images in one row

Answer (score 0):

'position: static' on .fm-userpreview can't be static if you want z-index to work.

From W3Schools: "position: static; is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page". This means the flow of the element is taking precedence over the z-index.

Also, z-index isn't necessary on the sub-elements (.fm-userpreview and .fm-userfullpreview) if I'm understanding your intent correctly.

Check out this forked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL8qd6tc/4/)

My approach was to place the element responsible for the hover after the expanding element. This means that the flow dictates it should be on top. I changed `position: static;` to `position: relative;` on the .fm-userpreview. Finally I removed z-index from both and added this to the containing element to make sure the it's above the rest on hover.

```
.col-md-3:hover {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Here's the full working code. If it's not what you intended, let me know and I can update it.

.css

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.invis { opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }

.col-md-3:hover {
  z-index: 2;
}

.fm-userpreview {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.fm-userpreview a{
  color: #fff;
}

.fm-userpreview p{
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fm-userpreview .fm-circle{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 5px;
}

.fm-userfullpreview{
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
}

/* Styling images */
.img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.fm-avatar{
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left:20px;
}
.fm-circle{

  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

.html

```
<div class="col-md12">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fm-userfullpreview" id="user-1">
          testsdagfasdgdsfghfdshsdfhsdfh
        </div>
        <div class="fm-userpreview" id="1">
          <div class="img fm-circle" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg')">
            <img class="invis" src="http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg">
            <p><a href="">{fullname}</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fm-userfullpreview" id="user-2">
          testsdagfasdgdsfghfdshsdfhsdfh
        </div>
        <div class="fm-userpreview" id="2">
          <div class="img fm-circle" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg')">
            <img class="invis" src="http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg">
            <p><a href="">{fullname}</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fm-userfullpreview" id="user-3">
          testsdagfasdgdsfghfdshsdfhsdfh
        </div>
        <div class="fm-userpreview" id="3">
          <div class="img fm-circle" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg')">
            <img class="invis" src="http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg">
            <p><a href="">{fullname}</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="fm-userfullpreview" id="user-4">
          testsdagfasdgdsfghfdshsdfhsdfh
        </div>
        <div class="fm-userpreview" id="4">
          <div class="img fm-circle" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg')">
            <img class="invis" src="http://i.imgur.com/fB929fH.jpg">
            <p><a href="">{fullname}</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

.js

```
$('.fm-userpreview').hover(function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#user-'+id).animate({
    width : 350,
  });
},function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#user-'+id).animate({
    width : 0,
  });
});
```

Comment: I added jsfiddle example to play with